# Access to Delayed::Worker instance

Tags: ruby, delayed-job

I'd like to access `Delayed::Worker` instance to call `say` on it to save some messages in `delayed_log` file. Is there any simple way to achieve such behaviour?

```
class SomeDelayedJob
    def perform
        worker = __?__ # Delayed::Worker instance which called that perform method
        worker.say('going to do x')
        do_x()
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use

`Delayed::Worker.logger.[info|error|warn|debug]`  "going to do x"

with some formatting :)

because **say** internally uses the same **logger** object

### Edit

`Delayed::Worker.logger.[info|error|warn|debug]`  "#{Process.pid} at #{Time.now} => going to do x"
Hope this help

Comment: I know, I'm using this right now... But Worker#say also formats those messages including worker id and time. I could format time myself (not DRY), but the former is more important eg. when I'd like to see what particular worker was doing in sequence.

Comment: Yup I know hence I mention formatting but if you are worried about the process id well you just add `Process.pid` I guess that would severe your need where as calling `say` I dont thinking that possible I may be wrong as well

Comment: edited the answer with what I mention in comment ,that the best I can help sorry

Comment: It's rather "hacky" way, I've wrote module and include it to all jobs:
    module Logging           
      def say(text, log_level=Logger::INFO)
        text = "#{Time.now.strftime('%FT%T%z')}: [Worker(pid:#{Process.pid})] #{text}"
        Delayed::Worker.logger.add(log_level, text)
      end
    end